# Description of site content types ignored?

Tags: content-type

I created site content type element and write some text into **Description** attribute. I deploy it (as farm solution). When I look at this content type in *Site Content types* section, I found that description is replaced by some default description.

**BUT** if I get description by powershell, **it is ok** - my custom description.

What is wrong here? I want to see my custom description in UI.

I tried this on two different computers/sharepoints and both with same result.

---

Here is some code if you want.

Content type definition is the default one, from Visual Studio 2010 *ContentType* template:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Parent ContentType: Položka (0x01) -->
    <ContentType ID="0x010000daa0d599fb4c4bbf60a844cf20c354"
           Name="CTwDescription - ContentType1"
           Group="Custom Content Types"
           Description="My Content Type"
           Inherits="TRUE"
           Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Powershell code to get the right description:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$ct = $w.ContnetTypes["CTwDescription - ContentType1"]
$w.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you deploy it (Site or Web)? You would also need to set Inherits="FALSE" which gives you total freedom on its definition. Also, make sure is not already in use when you deploy/re-deploy it as it might be that the updates would not be pushed to all children.

Comment: I have the default template for ContentType from Visual Studio => Web scoped feature, first time deploy through VS, no usage of it and I am checking site content types not list content type.

Inherits="FALSE" gives mi the Description to UI. But why it was already in object model with Inherits="TRUE" (and not showing in UI)???